# stored procedure input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i am creating a stored procedure in sql server 2008 such as this

```
-- the code
create procedure proce
@database varchar(50)
as
begin
select * from [@database].[dbo].[sometable]
end
```

the procedure is compiled

but when i execute the procedure using

```
-- here i execute it
execute proce 'somedatabase'
```

it throws an error

```
-- me gets error :(
Invalid object name '@database.dbo.sometable'
```

where am i going wrong???????

Comment: you would need to use dynamic TSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly parameterized the tableName. The only way you can do that is to make a dynamic SQL Statement.

eg,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proce @database VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
    SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @database + '].[dbo].[sometable]'
    EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
END
GO
```

- [Building Dynamic SQL In a Stored Procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe variables are allowed in that context, use the following which I've just confirmed works with your procedure:

```
exec('select * from [' + @database + '].[dbo].[sometable]')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go with this:

```
DECLARE @string AS NVARCHAR(500)
SET @string = 'select * from [' + @database + '].[dbo].[sometable]' 
EXEC (@string)
```

More more info refer: **[Dynamic SQL](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Executing_&_Dynamic_SQL)**